# Page 8 Enderton Elements of Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

See pg 8. He has set up a hierarchy where Vo = A= {all atoms}
and Vn+1=Vn U PVn

So far so good…

But he now goes on to state that we do not have enough sets, specifically we do not have the following infinite set:
{0,{0},{{0}},…}

And this is where he loses me. I don’t see why our hierarchy is not constructing this infinite set with increasing n.

He points out that 0 € V1, {0} € V2, {{0}} € V3 , etc. But since Vn-1 is a subset of Vn then the set {0,{0},{{0}}} € V3, and so it would seems we *are* constructing our infinite set. What am I missing here? I also don’t follow how the infinite union Vw=Vo U V1 U V2 constructs anything new, since Vn-1 is a subset of Vn and therefore Vn-1 U Vn = Vn. Please tell me what my mistake is and what I am missing here?
Thanks !
Joe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Without the Axiom of Infinity you cannot prove from the other axioms that an infinite set exists, unless the other axioms are inconsistent.

Comment: This is an informal treatment prior to his introducing The Axiom of Infinity, or an axiomatic approach. See page 7, 8

Answer (score 3):

We would be "building up to" the infinite set, but we wouldn't reach it. If you think we have created $\omega =  \{0,\{0\},\{\{0\}\},...\}$, then you would need to answer, which $V_n$ is $\omega$ part of?

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks Duncan! BTW as I work through text, I will have others Qs. WHat is best way to proceed, one ongoing thread e.g. Ederton El Set Th Questions, or new posted question for each question.

Comment: You should make a new posted question for each question.